# Getting empty data from Axios Get in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

I'm trying to get data from the database (mongoose) to client-side(React) but only getting empty data.

I tried many ways that researched from StackOverflow but those are not solving my problem.

I can get the data by using a console log from the backend. Also can get the data if I change a character from vscode. I mean if vscode sends a command to the refresh page the console log gives me what I want.

Here is the console log from React component. You can see console log gives 3 result and first 2 is empty and 3 rd one is the code I want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUS95.png)

Here is the React component that I have a problem with. You can look at the codes between stars(***).

```
  const hours = [...Array(24).keys()]
  const [unAvailableDate, setunAvailableDate] = useState([])
  
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/appointment')
    .then(data => setunAvailableDate(data.data.map(value => parseInt(value.Hour))))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [1])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(unAvailableDate)
      hours.forEach(num =>  {
          //check hours if unavailabe in blockHours
          if(unAvailableDate.includes(num)) {  
            const unavailableHours = {
              time: num + ":00",
              date:'' ,
              available: false
            }
            times.push(unavailableHours)
          }else {
            const allHours= {
              time: num + ":00",
              available: true,
            } 
            times.push(allHours)
          }
        })
     
      // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [unAvailableDate])
```

Also here is my controller page

```
// get and post block appointment hours

export const getBlockHours = async (req, res) => {
    await BlockApphours.find()
        .then(foundBlockHours => res.json(foundBlockHours))
};
export const createBlockHours = async (req, res) => {
    
        const createBlocks = new BlockApphours ({
            Date: req.body.Date,
            Hour: req.body.Hour
        
        });
        await createBlocks.save();

    
    console.log("succesfully added the block hours");
    res.redirect("/appointment")
}
```

Here is the router page

```
//Make An Appointment

router. route ("/make-appointment")
    .get(makeApp)
    .post(makeApp)
    
//block hours and get data
router.route("/appointment")
    .get(getBlockHours)
    .post(createBlockHours)

export default router;
```

Here is the schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const blockApphours = mongoose.Schema({
    Date: Date,
    Hour: String,
})

const BlockApphours = mongoose.model("BlockApphours", blockApphours);

export default BlockApphours;
```

Comment: The `save` method (as in `createBlocks.save()`) is async. You should wait for it to resolve before redirecting; you're not giving the backend enough time to persist your data before trying to read it. Also, I wouldn't recommend using redirects in API call responses. Stick with REST standards and you'll generally have an easier time

Comment: @Phil Thanks for answering but I tried async-await but It didn't work. can you explain more clearly, please?

Comment: Update the code in your question and I might be able to see where you're going wrong

Comment: Added the async await codes but actually I didint understand what do I need to change? - @Phil

Comment: The code in your _"controller page"_ snippet certainly looks better now (though the `await` in `getBlockHours` is not necessary). FYI your _"router page"_ code snippet appears to be just a copy of your _"controller page"_ snippet.

Comment: Sorry i just added the router codes. Also I updated the component codes. It should works but I didn't. If I change something on vs code the everything work but if I refresh page it doesn't work. The only problem looks like use effect doesn't update when useState change.